# Drag and drop using html5 in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I recently followed this tutorial http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/ and I can't get it to work. In IE it is complaining that **Error: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference** and I don't have any idea why. I tried this in chrome and get no error, however, the drag and drop does not work. Here is my html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/dndimg.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css"/>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAADYbHHQrNWPElNtE4hn2g1hQhn5tTlmnhbGVHENfXgw8ik0kvARSWpfuAdtdt1KqinQpUokxB7SpcsQ"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/dndimg.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dropbox"><span id="droplabel">Drop file here...</span>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
</div>

<br/>
<img id="preview" src="" alt="[ preview will display here ]"/>
</body>
</html>
```

And the js file:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
var dropbox = document.getElementById("dropbox")

// init event handlers
$("#dropbox").get(0).addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter, false)
$("#dropbox").get(0).addEventListener("dragexit", dragExit, false)
$("#dropbox").get(0).addEventListener("dragover", dragOver, false)
$("#dropbox").get(0).addEventListener("drop", dropAction, false);

// init the widgets
$("#progressbar").progressbar();
});

  function dragEnter(evt) {
evt.stopPropagation();
evt.preventDefault();
  }

 function dragExit(evt) {
evt.stopPropagation();
evt.preventDefault();
 }

  function dragOver(evt) {
evt.stopPropagation();
evt.preventDefault();
   }

  function drop(evt) {
evt.stopPropagation();
evt.preventDefault();

var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
var count = files.length;

// Only call the handler if 1 or more files was dropped.
if (count > 0)
    handleFiles(files);
   }


  function handleFiles(files) {
var file = files[0];

document.getElementById("droplabel").innerHTML = "Processing " + file.name;

var reader = new FileReader();

// init the reader event handlers
reader.onprogress = handleReaderProgress;
reader.onload = handleReaderLoadEnd;

// begin the read operation
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  function handleReaderProgress(evt) {
if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    var loaded = (evt.loaded / evt.total);

    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: loaded * 100 });
}
 }

  function handleReaderLoadEnd(evt) {
$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 100 });

var img = document.getElementById("preview");
img.src = evt.target.result;
  }
```

Its probably something simple I'm missing here, thanks in advance for any answers

Comment: have you tried the jQuery UI drag and drop... it's much easier

Comment: Which version of IE? addEventListener doesn't work in IE<9

Comment: For start the doc type is not the `<!DOCTYPE html>` for html5

Comment: @mgetz I have not ill look into that

Comment: @rob I believe its version 10

Comment: @aristos sorry I'm not very familiar with html 5 I'll look up what to change it to

Comment: @Andy The very first line on aspx page.... `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Comment: @Aristos ahh I see just get rid of the extra stuff. Thank you

Comment: Instead of `$("#dropbox").get(0).addEventListener` do `$("#dropbox").on`

Comment: @aristos well that fixed one error but now its saying google is undefined in the line where I use `google.load()`

Comment: @robertc I changed them all to     `$("#dropbox").on.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter, false)`

Comment: Why did you do that when I said *instead*?

Comment: @Andy You also load the jQuery version 1, is better to load the latest. https://developers.google.com/loader/

Comment: @robertc Oh I thought I needed to use the addEventListener. Is it not necessary?

Comment: Oh no. Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368034/file-upload-using-html5s-drag-and-drop-in-asp-net/18369594#18369594

refer to this question, this might be helpful.