# HTML5 drag and drop, Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to HTML5 features to implement drag and drop file uploads.

This is what I have done so far:

```
<form id="form" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="danger">Drag and Drap</div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "fileUpload.aspx"); 
xhr.send(data);
```

.Net:

```
public void fileUpload() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files; i++)
    {
    }
}
```

I am not able to hit fileUpload method, fiddler gives no informations. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Need more information on your question esp. full client script

Comment: Would you prefer using some library for this feature ?

Comment: nope, don't want to use any jquery library or other third party library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope my detailed tutorial on Html5 drag and drop in the following post will be helpful.

Stack OverFlow link:

[File upload using HTML5's drag and drop in Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368034/file-upload-using-html5s-drag-and-drop-in-asp-net/18369594#18369594)

Tutorial:

http://programmingusingdotnet.blogspot.com/2013/08/aspnet-drag-and-drop-file-uploads-using.html